Flutter not releasing memory (garbage collector not working)
I am making an application on flutter which shows a slideshow, but it is not releasing memory after the slideshow is over, below is the snippet of my code. It will be of great help if you could guide in resolving this memory issue, I am trying to solve it for months, I don't understand why my application is not releasing memory.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameApp({super.key});
  @override
  State<GameApp> createState() => _GameAppState();
}

class _GameAppState extends State<GameApp> {
  List<Widget> listWidget = [];
  int currentIndex = 0;
  Timer _timer = Timer(Duration.zero, () {});
  Widget gameWidget = const Text('This slideshow has 26 images');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listWidget = [
      const Text(
        'Lets start adding images',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
      ),
      Image.asset('assets/images/b1.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/b2.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/b3.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/1.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/2.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/3.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/4.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/5.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/6.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/7.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/8.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/9.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/10.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/11.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/12.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/13.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/14.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/15.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/16.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/17.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/18.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/19.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/20.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/21.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/22.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/23.webp'),
      const Text(
        'Thanks for watching the Slideshow',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
      ),
    ];

    // Schedule the timer to change the widget every 3 seconds
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer timer) {
      if (currentIndex < listWidget.length) {
        setState(() {
          gameWidget = listWidget[currentIndex];
        });
        currentIndex++;
      } else {
        _timer.cancel(); // Stop the timer once all widgets have been shown
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Stack(children: [gameWidget])));
  }
}

I tried multiple things but can't seem to get there.

To ensure that you are disposing of your slide show quickly you could add the dispose method. One more suggestion is to initialize your timer as null instead null since below you are giving it value anyway but that is less relevant.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameApp({super.key});
  @override
  State<GameApp> createState() => _GameAppState();
}

class _GameAppState extends State<GameApp> {
  List<Widget> listWidget = [];
  int currentIndex = 0;
  Timer? _timer;
  Widget gameWidget = const Text('This slideshow has 26 images');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listWidget = [
      const Text(
        'Lets start adding images',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
      ),
      Image.asset('assets/images/b1.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/b2.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/b3.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/1.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/2.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/3.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/4.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/5.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/6.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/7.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/8.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/9.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/10.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/11.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/12.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/13.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/14.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/15.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/16.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/17.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/18.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/19.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/20.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/21.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/22.webp'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/23.webp'),
      const Text(
        'Thanks for watching the Slideshow',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
      ),
    ];

    // Schedule the timer to change the widget every 3 seconds
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer timer) {
      if (currentIndex < listWidget.length) {
        setState(() {
          gameWidget = listWidget[currentIndex];
        });
        currentIndex++;
      } else {
        _timer?.cancel(); // Stop the timer once all widgets have been shown
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel(); // Dispose of the timer
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Stack(children: [gameWidget])));
  }
}

